# Generate random audio or playing a file at different offset

Tags: python, python-2.7, audio

On Python 2.7 is there a way to generate an audio file or an audio data as a string, more especifically white noise.

I'm using

```
winsound.PlaySound(sound, flags)
```

However with this function I can't control when the audio starts playing and I need Python to play a random white noise signal (even if it comes from the same file but starts playing at a different time).

In other words, can someone help me generate a random white noise audio and then play it asynchronously in the background? Or can someone recommend me an audio module

Comment: `winsound` is a very minimal module. If you want to do anything more than "play this sound", it's not the right answer; go search on PyPI. (Actually, playing it asynchronously in the background, you can do the same way you can do _anything_ asynchronously in the background—with `threading`, or `multiprocessing`. But you still won't be able to control it in any way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are open to external libraries, I've worked with [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) that offers off the shelf white noise generator from its `pydub.generators` modules.

Details about pydub installation and other features can be found [here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub).

Below code import needed modules (as described in comments) , creates a 5 sec white_noise audio_segment and then plays in the background using `thread`.

Hope this helps.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment           #to save whitenoise to audio_segment
from pydub.generators import WhiteNoise  #to generate white noise
from pydub.playback import play          #needed to play the audio segement
from threading import Thread             #for async background 


#whitenoise duration
duration = 5000  #duration in millisec
wn = WhiteNoise().to_audio_segment(duration=duration)


def play_white_noise(segment,duration):
    """ play whitenoise for given duration """
    play(segment)

#instantiate thread
white_noise = Thread(target=play_white_noise, args=(wn,duration))

#start the thread
white_noise.start()

#Thread is run in the background. Do your stuff 
print " play noise in background"
```

Comment: This returns `File "C:\Users\bryce\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 60, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\bryce\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpru7uh7sq.wav'`